# Sorting dates throws exception TypeError: data.createdAt.sort is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Sorting dates throws exception `TypeError: data.createdAt.sort is not a function`. I would like to sort and display the latest record first in my react app.

```
{
                                displayWinner.map(data => (
                                <div key={data.id}className="oldwinner">
                                    <div className="winnerIcon">
                                        <img src="/images/trophy1.png"></img>
                                        <span key={data.winner} className="winner name">{data.winner}</span>
                                        <span key={data.createdAt} className="winner date">{moment(data.createdAt.sort((a, b) => b - a)).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                ))
                            }
```

[image]

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-edison-l4shu?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Is `data.createdAt` an array that is sortable? Can you share what the `displayWinner` value is that you are mapping, and describe what is you are trying to do? From what I can tell it seems you are attempting to sort a single date string.

Comment: I have added the data that iterates through that section,

Comment: Right, so `data.createdAt` is a dateTime string, there isn't a `.sort` you can call. Are you wanting to sort the `displayWinner` array by this `createdAt` element property?

Comment: displayWinner has the list of all records from the table displaying under Previous winner section. I would like to display the latest record on top

Comment: Yes I would to sort displayWinner array by this createdAt element property

Comment: I have added another screen shot in the question

Comment: Do you have some sample `displayWinner` data we could work with?

Comment: @drew I have added a codeSandbox link for reference

Comment: @DrewReese I have added a codeSandbox link for sample reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the data *then* map it, `sort((a, b) => moment(b.createdAt) - moment(a.createdAt))`. Take each element and convert the `createdAt` property to a momentjs DateTime object for numerical comparison

```
{displayWinner
  .sort((a, b) => moment(b.createdAt) - moment(a.createdAt))
  .map((data,) => (
    <div key={data.createdAt} className="oldwinner">
      <div className="winnerIcon">
        <img key="data" src="/images/trophy1.png"></img>
        <span key={data.winner} className="winner name">
          {data.winner}
        </span>
        <span key={data.createdAt} className="winner date">
          {moment(data.createdAt).format("DD-MMM-YYYY")}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
```

[image: Edit sorting-dates-throws-exception-typeerror-data-createdat-sort-is-not-a-function]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorting should be done before mapping the values

```
{
  displayWinner.sort((a, b) => moment(b.createdAt).format('DD-MMM-YYYY') - moment(a.createdAt).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')).map(data => (
                                    <div key={data.id}className="oldwinner">
                                        <div className="winnerIcon">
                                            <img src="/images/trophy1.png"></img>
                                            <span key={data.winner} className="winner name">{data.winner}</span>
                                            <span key={data.createdAt} className="winner date">{moment(data.createdAt).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    ))
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 cases when you can get this `TypeError: x.sort is not a function`. When you are trying to call `sort` on `string` or `Object`. In your case you first need to sort values then map.

```js
{
    displayWinner.sort((a, b) => b - a).map(data => (
        <div key={data.id} className="oldwinner">
            <div className="winnerIcon">
                <img src="/images/trophy1.png"></img>
                <span key={data.winner} className="winner name">{data.winner}</span>
                <span key={data.createdAt} className="winner date">
                    { moment(data.createdAt.format('DD-MMM-YYYY') }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    ))
}
```